# Quasar Router routes not found

Tags: javascript, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm using for the first time quasar router, I already know how to use Vue router and this one should be almost the same, and it quite is but the problem is it doesn't work, I have created a Login Page and tried to insert the route in routes.ts file but now i can't access the main page neither the login one, and when I look in the console I get this error: "Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:9000/src/layouts/MainLayout.vue".
Here's the code:

**Routes.ts**

```
import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    // Main Page
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/QuestionsPage.vue') },
    ],
  },

  {
    path: '/login',
    component: () => import('pages/LoginPage.vue'),
  },

  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/ErrorNotFound.vue'),
  },
];

export default routes;
```

**In case you need the login page and the main one:**

```
<script setup lang="ts"></script>

<template>
  <q-page padding>
    <h1>Login</h1>
  </q-page>
</template>
```

```
<script setup>
console.log('test');
</script>

<template>
  <q-page padding>
    <h1>Main Page</h1>
  </q-page>
</template>
```

**File structure:**

[image]

Comment: What is your project file structure?

Comment: I'll edit the question and attach it

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the `<router-view>` in your MainLayout.vue inside the `<q-page-container` ?

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#router-view

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).